# API HTTP/Request2.php to CURL

Tags: php, apache, api

I have an API that requires HTTP/Request2.php.

(  Apache HTTP client from HTTP Components (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)

can I use CURL instead , is there is any way not to use this Component ?

here is the API code

```
<?php
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$request = new Http_Request2('http://ww');
$url = $request->getUrl();

$headers = array(
    // Request headers
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => '{subscription key}',
);

$request->setHeader($headers);

$parameters = array(
    // Request parameters
);

$url->setQueryVariables($parameters);

$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);

// Request body
$request->setBody("{body}");

try
{
    $response = $request->send();
    echo $response->getBody();
}
catch (HttpException $ex)
{
    echo $ex;
}

?>
```

Comment: Not enough information here to give good direction.  You should theoretically be able to do this using cURL since at the end of the day all you are likely doing is forming an HTTP request.  Now whether it is practical to rewrite code to use cURL is a different question altogether.

Comment: I update my question with the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing this question was asked almost a year ago, I thought I should contribute an answer since I came up with the same problem and it may have happened to others as well.

Judging by the code given and the `Ocp-Apic-Subscription-Key` header, I guess you are trying to communicate with [Microsoft's Vision API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/computer-vision-api) ([Documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc)). Here's what I used in order to communicate with the API via cURL:

```php
$headers = array(
    // application/json is also a valid content-type
    // but in my case I had to set it to octet-steam
    // for I am trying to send a binary image
    'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {subscription key}'
);
$curl = $curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true); // don't cache curl request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, '{api endpoint}');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); // http POST request
// if content-type is set to application/json, the POSTFIELDS should be:
// json_encode(array('url' => $body))
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the transfer as a string of the return value
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// disabling SSL checks may not be needed, in my case though I had to do it
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$curlError = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```